# Zend Fatal Error Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message

Tags: zend-framework, zend-loader

am working with a Zend framework project fine in localhost, but when I put it in a public web server
the folowing error comes:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'DocType' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:../application/views/helpers/' in /path/to/my/appli/application/library/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php:412 
Stack trace: 
#0 /path/to/my/appli/application/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(1182): Zend_Loader_PluginLoader->load('DocType') 
#1 /path/to/my/appli/application/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(618): Zend_View_Abstract->_getPlugin('helper', 'docType') 
#2 /path/to/my/appli/application/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(344): Zend_View_Abstract->getHelper('docType') 
#3 [internal function]: Zend_View_Abstract->__call('docType', Array) 
#4 /path/to/my/appli/appli in /path/to/my/appli/application/library/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php on line 412
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doctype is case sensitive you should write $view->doctype not $view->docType

Answer (score 0):

problem solved
i just removed the folowing lines from my bootstrap:

```
protected function _initDoctype() {
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->docType('XHTML1_TRANSITIONAL');
}
```

and i dont know why that works fine when i delete it :/
(this function cause no problem in my localhost, but not in the remote server)